# Run SQL query on select option from dropdown

Tags: php, mysql

I am new here so I hope you all are ignore my mistakes.
I am trying to run a sql query on select an option from the dropdown list.
Like I have the drop-down

```
<select>
    <option>Possible</option>
    <option>Converted</option>
    <option>Not Possible</option>
</select>
```

on selection of "Converted" I want to run a query that will copy and delete that row and on selection of "Not Possible" it will just delete the row.Let me know how I can do it in simplest way because I search google and their are some technical answers which are not understandable for me at this time.

Thanks.

Here is my code

```
<select onchange="change_status(this.value,<?php echo $val['id'] ?>)">
    <option <?php if($val['status']==''||$val['status']==null||$val['status']=='Possible conversion'){?>selected<?php }?>>Possible conversion</option>
    <option <?php if($val['status']=='Coverted customer'){?>selected<?php }?> name="conver_ted" value="conver_ted">Coverted customer</option>
    <option <?php if($val['status']=='Not meeting requirement'){?>selected<?php }?>>Not meeting requirement</option>
</select>

<?php if(isset($_POST['conver_ted'])){echo "working";} ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is very basic thing. You should search it. And first try in your way.

Comment: @HarshBarach I search it and many of them doing this by using jquery/javascript and php at same time but can we do this just using php?

Comment: yes, of course you can do it with only php.

Comment: @HarshBarach can you please guide me what to use because $_GET and $_POST is normally used when we submit a form and then execute the query any $_REQUEST is upon requesting some option. which one is the best to use in my situation? Because I am just selecting something to run query.

Comment: You should use $_POST.

Comment: paste your full code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind onchange event to select element and perform ajax call upon selection of value.

Within ajax call you need to retrieve value of select form element using **$_POST** superglobal array variable upon form submission.

Please refer example code snippet as mentioned below.

```
<?php
   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
   {
        $select_element_value=$_POST['select_element'];
        switch($select_element_value)
        {
            case 'Converted':
                   //Copy row and delete
            break;
            case 'Not Possible':
                //Perform delete
            break;
            default:
            break;
        } 
   } 
?>
```

Comment: can you tell me what is the request_method in this code?
Thanks

Comment: because I am getting this error
 PHP Notice: Undefined index: REQUEST_METHOD in index.php on line 9

Comment: @QararUlHassan Please refer to documentation mentioned in following url : http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php